# OpenCart 2: URL and Reviews problems with SSL on

Tags: ssl, opencart2.x

I set up SSL on my shop, and I get 2 problems.

Fist one is that the urls of tbe shop (seo on) are now like this: [https://example.com/index.php?*route*=name-of-the-product](https://example.com/index.php?_route_=name-of-the-product) instead of http://example.com/name-of-the-product (without SSL).

The second one is that pagination for the reviews stop working. I can't go to page 2 or 3 and etc. to see the reviews. When I try to see page 2 or 3 and etc., I receive a notification in the address bar that says "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources".

Does anyone knows how to fix thise problems.

My OpenCart is 2.0.2.0 version.

Answer (score 4):

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /

#This setting force logo url to it's home page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.yourdomain.com/? [R=301,L,NE,NC]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```